# What could be the meaning of 主治陳進陽草菅人命, 插管插到死, 腎臟料 and 人命?

Tags: meaning-in-context, culture

What could be the context of banners put up in front of a hospital with the following text:

> 主治陳進陽草菅人命
>   插管插到死
>   腎臟料 人命

For the name and location of the hospital, or a high resolution version, see [the image as I uploaded it to Wikimedia Commons today](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Banners_reading_%E4%B8%BB%E6%B2%BB%E9%99%B3%E8%B0%81%E9%99%BD%E8%8D%89%E8%8F%85%E4%BA%BA%E5%91%BD,_%E6%8F%92%E7%AE%A1%E6%8F%92%E5%88%B0%E6%AD%BB,_%E8%85%8E%E8%87%9F%E6%96%99_and_%E4%BA%BA%E5%91%BD,_put_up_on_Section_2,_Shipai_Road_(%E7%9F%B3%E7%89%8C%E8%B7%AF%E4%BA%8C%E6%AE%B5)_in_front_of_the_Taipei_Veterans_General_Hospital_(%E5%8F%B0%E5%8C%97%E6%A6%AE%E6%B0%91%E7%B8%BD%E9%86%AB%E9%99%A2)_seen_on_31_October_2017.jpg), which shows the banners:

[image: See https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Banners_reading_主治陳谁陽草菅人命,_插管插到死,_腎臟料_and_人命,_put_up_on_Section_2,_Shipai_Road_(石牌路二段)_in_front_of_the_Taipei_Veterans_General_Hospital_(台北榮民總醫院)_seen_on_31_October_2017.jpg]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

草菅人命 (disregard for human life)

插管插到死 (cause death due to intubation)

腎臟科 (Division of Nephrology)

人命 (human life)

According to the website of the 台北榮總腎臟科, 陳進陽 is an attending physician (主治醫師) of the Division of Nephrology (腎臟科).

[image]

Someone claimed that the doctor, Jinn-Yang Chen (陳進陽), has caused death of a patient because of medical malpractice (intubation).